# Unable to fit Items in comboBox in java

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I am completely new to java Swing and i am trying to fit my dictionary in combo box by which when i start typing in JTextField and it searches it in combo box from the starting Index of typed word and show me the words that starts with, Now the problem is i cant add my dictionary items in combo box ,I extract my dictionary words into a String array then Add up in ComboBox but it shows me nothing, whereas i am able to add around 20 items in it, Is ComboBox has limited space for item?? If yes ,Then refer me some other method by which i can make this type of thing.
Here its what i am doing

```
package swing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class swing1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form swing1
     */
    public swing1() throws FileNotFoundException {
        initComponents();

         FileReader fileread=null;
           String array[]=new String[107186];
           String input;
            String FileName="English.txt";
            fileread = new FileReader(FileName);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileread);
            int i=0;
            try {
                while((input=br.readLine())!=null)
                {
                  array[i]=input;
                    i++;
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            this.jComboBox1.addItem(array);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        textField1 = new java.awt.TextField();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField1.setText("textField1");

        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(159, 159, 159)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 142, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 169, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(72, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(204, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                          

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(swing1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(swing1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(swing1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(swing1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new swing1().setVisible(true);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(swing1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify  

    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private java.awt.TextField textField1;

}
```

I cant post Image due to my reputation less than 10 but tell you the answer , it show me this in combo box " [Ljava.lang.String;@43376 " 
I am using Netbeans and making my GUI using Drag and Drop, and i also put my dictionary elements in Model of comboBox Properties but it didn't give me my desired result

Help me !

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use

```
     JComboBox<String> jComboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>();
    //loop over your array and add them one by one
     for(String s:array)
         jComboBox1.addItem(s);
```

Comment: Thanx man it worked but it shows me limited elements , i have a dictionary around 1 lac words , does they fit in combo box or should i use other thing !

Comment: 1+, @Farrukh, or you can create a DefaultComboBoxModel with the Array and then add the model to the combo box. `i have a dictionary around 1 lac words` - I'm not sure what "1 lac" is, but I would guess the limit of the combo box is limited by the maximum size of the int value, since you need to be able to access the data by an index. If you think you have too many words, write a loop that adds integer objects to the combo box to see how many you can add.

Comment: Do you display words starting with the "typed word" in the combobox? If so, you do not need to add the whole array. You can add a key listener to your textField1 then select the matching strings in "array" with a given limit (MAXELTS of combobox to determine) and finally add them to your combobox.